# How to make measures to make my calculations grouped by year/month?

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to make count number of sessions for mentees.
I need make it filterable.

My table with new column:
[image]

I extract year and start of month in columns year_dt and month_dt.

Last 2 columns:

```
sessions_cnt_year = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNT('sessions'[session_id]),
    ALLEXCEPT('sessions', 'sessions'[mentee_id], 'sessions'[year_dt]))

sessions_cnt_month = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNT('sessions'[session_id]),
    ALLEXCEPT('sessions', 'sessions'[mentee_id], 'sessions'[month_dt]))
```

At this case I put new columns in table on sheet and get vusualization I need.
I use table with this columns:

1. values sessions_cnt_year without aggregation
2. distinct count mentee_id
3. count session_id.

But there's one problem. How can I switch sessions_cnt_year values on sessions_cnt_month values depending on slicers or filtering by another visualisation?

Model:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Create a real date dimension, not that horrid thing that PowerBI creates if you don't have a date dimension. Oh, and all the columns after mentor_domain_id are attributes of your calendar table, so remove them. Use the relationship between the your fact table and the date dimension to retrieve that information. 
What's wrong with COUNTROWS('FactTable') and then using CALCULATE to add/remove filters from the evaluation context?
Oh, sessions_counts: if you put MonthYear on rows and the count on values, you're done. Same with Year. If you really want to toggle, use parameters.

Comment: Thanks, but I still can't figure out how to make switch between year and month in sessions_cnt. This is column (it's like result of aggregation func in groupby) not measure which I can easily switch to another measure (by switch measure).

Answer (score 0):

In your power query while loading the file, you can set the data type of your "session_date_time" column to a date type.

This will allow you to use the hierarchy created by PowerBI to filter by Year/Month

Comment: I got some progress with my problem, check updated question, please.